# map reduce program to count Frequency of particular entity in a column of a table

Tags: java, scala, hadoop, mapreduce, word-count

We have a marketing report in form of tabular data set which schema looks like this:

[image]

[Link to the dataset](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1U2nIECYahTnSGbGjbGD-kD5DujRRBgtlgHwhqIL6WzY/edit?usp=sharing)

We need to **write a map reduce program** in order to find out the highest frequency of **Initial_referring** source site in order to find out which website most effective ad platform.

**Approach**

1. Remove rows having duplicate entities in distinct_id column.
2. Count frequency of each entity in initial_referring column.
3. Publish the result of frequency of each identity.

I am able to do this problem in Hive and pig but was not able to get the correct result in MapReduce program.

Any reference or piece of similar code can help.

Comment: What have you attempted that isn't working?  Why isn't it working?  Why must it be a mapreduce program if hive and pig are good enough?  Hive and pig do run as mapreduce jobs anyway.  You've tagged Scala on this question, are you writing your code in Scala or Java?

Comment: I attempted writing map reduce code in Java, but i am not able to get expected result.

Comment: Please show your code and be specific about your problems.  What exactly is incorrect about your result, or if you have error, what are those errors?